# Краш окна при использовании цикла while в Tkinter

Tags: python, ооп, tkinter

Суть кода заключается в том, чтобы отправлять какое-либо сообщение, когда нажали на какую-либо кнопку, и переставать его отправлять, когда эту кнопку нажали еще раз.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import keyboard
import time


class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.title('StartScript')
        self.window.geometry('300x200')
        self.window.resizable(False, False)

        self.start_btn = ttk.Button(text='Start', command=self.start)
        self.stop_btn = ttk.Button(text='Stop')
        self.lbl = tk.Label(text='Enter key:')
        self.ent = ttk.Entry()

        self.check = False

        self.position()

        self.window.mainloop()

    def position(self):
        self.start_btn.place(x=50, y=85)
        self.stop_btn.place(x=175, y=85)

    def start(self):
        self.stop_btn.place_forget()

        self.start_btn.place(x=110, y=120)
        self.ent.place(x=85, y=85)
        self.lbl.place(x=85, y=60)

        self.start_btn['command'] = self.mechanics

    def mechanics(self):
    user_key = self.ent.get()

    self.ent.place_forget()
    self.start_btn.place(x=50, y=85)
    self.stop_btn.place(x=175, y=85)

        def set_message():

            if self.check:
                self.check = False
            else:
                self.check = True

        keyboard.add_hotkey(user_key, set_message)

        while True:
            if self.check:
                keyboard.write('1000-7?\n')
                time.sleep(1)


app = App()
```

В целом, код выполняет свою задачу, но он рассчитан на неоднократное использование за 1 запуск. То есть в этой версии должна быть возможность перебиндить один хоткей на другой в самом окне программы. Но это не получается реализовать в связи с тем, что окно крашится на моменте запуска функции mechanics(). Хотя при бинде первой клавиши и после зависания программы (не закрывая ее) код работает корректно. Я подозреваю, что это может происходить из-за цикла while, но точно не уверен и как сделать так, чтобы все работало корректно не знаю. Хелп ми плз.